Weighted mean of percentages on percentages
I have a question about weighted means.
Usually, when you calculate a weighted mean, you multiply values by weights that usually are quantities, e.g., the number of children with blue eyes in a class.
Suppose that the weight is not a number but a percentage. Is it correct to apply a weighted mean if you have the values that are % and the weights that are %?
It means to weight on % and not to absolute counts.
Thank you in advance

Depends on what you mean by correct. If you make this multiplication you will indeed end up with a number between 0 and 1 (assuming you use 0.05 for 5% etcetera). So you could write that as a percentage again. The interpretation is then, if the outcome is 0% it means the percentages in the weighted columns were all zero. If the outcome is 100% it means that the percentages in the weighted columns were all 100%. And in between it works out as well. However, a percentage is usually interpreted as a percentage of something, and that something is not a very intuitive thing here. And it does not correspond to the weighted average of the total, which would be an obvious confusion.
For example, if you have 2 / 4 A (50%) and 2 / 8 B (25%). And you weigh A and B both equally, let's say 1. Then one way to get the weighted percentage is 4 / 12 ~ 33.3%. If you take percentages first though, you would weigh 50% and 25% equally, ending up with 37.5%. Both of these percentages are hard to interpret correctly as a percentage.

I would say it's rather the opposite: you weight with probability distributions rather than amounts (which you normalise by sum of amounts).
an unweighted mean is the average over a dataset.
This is the weighted mean assuming a uniform distribution (ie weight = 1/N)
a weighted mean is just the average with a different probability distribution, weight = p_i
so calculating the average score in a school =
weighted mean of average score in class times probability of being in class x (proportion of children in class x).
you are used to working with frequencies, which are then normalised by the sum of those frequencies (to turn into a probability distribution).
